# How can I declare a date type parameter in JDBC request in Jmeter

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter

On executing my SP in Jmeter as below

- QueryType:Callable Statement

  - Query:execute [QC].[usp_GetCallCounts] ?,?,?,?,?,?
  - Parameter Values: 33,'12-01-2016','12-15-2016',74861,0,Evaluator
  - Parameter Types: INTEGER,DATE,DATE,INTEGER,BIT,VARCHAR

    [Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5b4x.png)

    - I get this Response message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
  - Log file details are as follow:

  2018-01-12 18:50:04,887 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
  2018-01-12 18:50:04,888 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
  2018-01-12 18:50:04,890 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
  2018-01-12 18:50:05,395 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
  2018-01-12 18:50:05,395 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
  2018-01-12 18:50:05,395 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
  2018-01-12 18:50:05,395 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
  2018-01-12 18:50:05,396 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
  2018-01-12 18:50:05,396 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
  2018-01-12 18:50:05,396 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
  2018-01-12 18:50:20,055 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
  2018-01-12 18:50:20,055 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
  2018-01-12 18:50:20,055 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
  2018-01-12 18:50:20,056 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

Comment: can you show full error? can you show how you call it outside JMeter?

Comment: Statementtype:Callable statement
execute [QC].[usp_GetCallCounts] ?,?,?,?,?,?

PArameter values:
33,'12/01/2016','12/15/2016',74861,0,'Evaluator'

PArameter types:
Integer,date,date,Integer,bit,varchar

Comment: SAmpler Result:
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-01-10 18:24:24 PKT
Load time: 17945
Connect Time: 17692
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 10
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 10
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 000
Response message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Response:
No MEssage

Comment: I meant in jmeter.log, and add your text to question by clicking edit below you question

Comment: @user7294900 Can u plz guide how can I attach the jmeter.log file here?

Comment: Copy and exception from log. Edit question and  paste it

Comment: @user7294900 I have added the log. Kindly look into it

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same problem today, and after debugging and removing each parameter and value one by one we found out the problem is with the DATE parameter type.

So my advice would be to replace the DATE object with an TIMESTAMP object, since that's how we have done that, and it seems to work.

- Parameter Types: INTEGER,TIMESTAMP,TIMESTAMP,INTEGER,BIT,VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

As per [reference doc](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) you need to use UPPER Case names as per:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html

So it would be :

> DATE

Comment: Tried with UPPER case but no luck.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you did and jmeter.log ?

Comment: how can I attach the log file here?